# Aligning Metro Tiles in a Single File column?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Is it possible to align start menu tile groups into a column that is just a single block wide?  I can't seem to logically group things 8 tiles at a time, so I wind up with a very long section of very small groups.  If there's a program that can override Microsoft's default layout that would be nice.  I'm familiar with .NET, but have really never done anything system oriented.  If anybody has any suggestions on where to start with writing an app to do this, that would be very helpful as well.

Here's basically what my start screen looks like now:
[image: Before]

Here's how I would like it to look:
[image: After]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that behavior (a column that is a single square tile wide) is not possible, by design.  The shortest width that you can have is 2 tiles wide, to accommodate the wide tiles.

Comment: Seems like a pretty poor design choice to me. If I don't want wide tiles in a particular group, shouldn't that be my decision to make?